# excel formula to pull values from another sheet if number in one column is the same

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to automate an invoice and need some help.  I have my invoice formatted on one tab, and all orders are entered on a separate tab.  The 'Orders' tab has multiple columns -- Invoice ID, Invoice Date, Customer ID, etc.  Each product within an order is entered on a new row with the same Invoice ID.

I have formulas set up in the cells on my 'Invoice' tab to grab the information from the 'Orders' tab when I simply input the Invoice ID.  However,  how do I modify the formula to get all the products under one Invoice ID to populate on the invoice?  Below is my current formula:

=INDEX(Orders!E:E,MATCH(Invoice!$I$10,Orders!A:A,0)

Invoice ID is in cell I10 on the 'Invoice' tab and column A on the 'Orders' tab.
Product ID is in column E on the 'Orders' tab.

The formula works great on the first product, but how do I get the other products with the same Invoice ID to appear on the invoice in the rows below the first item?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
=INDEX(Orders!E:E, aggregate(15, 6, row($2:$999)/(Invoice!$I$10=Orders!A$2:A$999), row(1:1)))
```