# Vlookup Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, rows, vlookup

In 'Sheet1', I essentially need to type a person's name in a certain cell, (in this case Jim,), and have it lookup a list of names in Column A on 'Sheet2'.

[image: General Idea]

I have success in showing the 1st row (with multiple different styles of forumulas, vlookup, index match.etc) but in most cases, there are 2-4 rows of data. Upon searching for the name, I need it to show row 1,2,3,4 if applicable.

Comment: use vlookup() or an index() match() combination - advantage of index&match is that the indexing column can be in the middle... This post should give you some ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35232799/4961700

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. In fact, it was answered as little as [an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336499).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished writing my answer at the same time as @Jeeped's comment and the other answer appeared.

Still worth sharing perhaps because it shows how you can pull across the formula for several columns

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$I$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10)/(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10=$D$2),ROW()-ROW($3:$3))-ROW($1:$1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($C:$C)),"")
```

The data on the first sheet looks like this

[image]

And the second sheet is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

step one: find the first larry

```
=MATCH(C9,C1:C7,0)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL0rm.png

step two, create a range that begins +1 after first match row, and look for next larry

```
=MATCH(C9,INDIRECT("C" & B11+1):C7,0)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/giYDI.png

step three, fill in my arrays

```
=INDEX(C1:C7,$B$11)

=INDEX(INDIRECT("E" & $B$11+1):$E$7,$B$12)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sACGM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly8uj.png

Comment: I am not sure that that is correct, you can even look at the example that I work through, where the name I search for is unsorted, as an example

Comment: Oh i see, you're defining new match ranges via the indirect.  I'll delete my other comment.